# Replies to my comments

Tags: youtube, comments

So I comment on a video, and someone replies, the little notification pops up and I can read about half of the comment.  There's no 'read more', so I click and it goes to the video in question but not the comment.
And searching is fruitless because the search does not look through replies.

How can I find that person's reply without digging through three thousand nested comments & replies?

Answer (score 0):

You can scroll down to the last comment (in order to load all comments) and then simply 
press <kbd>**`CTRL`**</kbd> + <kbd>**`F`**</kbd> and type in your nickname/channel name/part of the reply.

If you got a better kind of mouse you can do so-called "pro-gamer move" and click the middle mouse button a.k.a the wheel and drag your mouse down by few centimeters - this will trigger automatic mass-scrolling.